# Some doubts about how it work this iTextSharp application?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, itext

I am pretty new in C# and this is the first time that I work with **iTextSharp** (the **iText** porting for C#) and I have the following doubt about how work an old application that I am remade from 0.

In this application there is a controller class containing a method that generate a PDF file into a method having the following signature: **private byte[] GetPdf(int id, bool withcomments)**

In this method I can find something like this:

```
private byte[] GetPdf(int id, bool withcomments)
{

byte[] buffer = null;

using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 100, 50))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

    document.Open();

    Font arialtitle = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 14);
    Font arialtext = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9);

    iTextSharp.text.Font title = new iTextSharp.text.Font(arialtitle);
    title.SetStyle(iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);

    iTextSharp.text.Font bold = new iTextSharp.text.Font(arialtext);
    title.SetStyle(iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);

    iTextSharp.text.Font text = new iTextSharp.text.Font(arialtext);
    title.SetStyle(iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

    PdfPTable table = null;
    PdfPCell cell = null;

    Image img = null;
    string filename = null;

    table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.WidthPercentage = 98;
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(a.Title, title)) { FixedHeight = 70 };
    cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
    table.AddCell(cell);
    document.Add(table);

    table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.SetWidths(new int[] { 100, 500 });
    table.WidthPercentage = 98;
    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description:", bold)) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 50, PaddingTop = 15 });
    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(a.ShortSummary, text)) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 50, PaddingTop = 15 });
     document.Add(table);

     .........................................................
     .........................................................
     .........................................................

     return buffer;
}
```

I have the following doubts:

1) What exactly do the **using** statement? And why, in the previous code, the iTextSharp **Document** object is created into the **using** statement? What is the difference from the classic creation into the code?

2) As you can see in the previous code there is some graphic settings putted into {...} blocks.

For example something like this:

```
table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description:", bold)) { Border = PdfPCell.BOTTOM_BORDER, Padding = 5, MinimumHeight = 50, PaddingTop = 15 });
```

in which the **PdfCell** graphics settings are setted into the {SETTINGS} bloks settings the values of **Border**, **Padding**, **MinimumHeight** and **PaddingTop** properties (that belong to an object instance of a class named **Rectangle**

The thing that I can't understand if these settings objects belong tu **iTextSharp** framework or if the **Rectangle** class is a custom class created by the developers of the application that I have to rebuild.

I have this doubt because I know that, in iTextSharp, if I want to set a padding value I simply can do something like: **cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;** withoud using a **Padding** object

To let you better understand the situation this is the **Rectangle** class content that is present into my old project:

```
#region Assembly itextsharp.dll, v5.3.4.0
// C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver1\ExternalAssemblies\itextsharp.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace iTextSharp.text
{
    public class Rectangle : Element, IElement
    {
        public const int BOTTOM_BORDER = 2;
        public const int BOX = 15;
        public const int LEFT_BORDER = 4;
        public const int NO_BORDER = 0;
        public const int RIGHT_BORDER = 8;
        public const int TOP_BORDER = 1;
        public const int UNDEFINED = -1;

        protected BaseColor backgroundColor;
        protected int border;
        protected BaseColor borderColor;
        protected BaseColor borderColorBottom;
        .................................................
        .................................................
        .................................................
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**using keyword**

The `using` keyword is used to ensure proper disposal of class instances implementing `IDisposable`. The `IDisposable` pattern is used to manage releasing of unmanaged resources (file handles, connections to DB, memory streams ...).

More info can be found on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx).

The general rule is thumb is that if you are using a class that implements `IDisposable`, you must (or it's a strong recommendation at least) use it through the `using` keyword pattern.

**iTextSharp**

The settings objects you refer to belond to iTextSharp. For example, the `Rectangle` class is defined in iTextSharp, in the `iTextSharp.text` namespace.

`PdfPCell` also belongs to iTextSharp.

The only reason you can see the `Rectangle` class implementation is because iTextSharp provides source and symbols alongside the executable version of its DLL, so that you are able to look into its code. However, this is not some code that you can modify, or that you own. You are just referencing the iTextSharp assembly.

Comment: ok, but now my doubt is: to use Rectangle class and PdfCell class I first have to build it but here I can't see the call to the constructos of these class...why?

Comment: I can see the call to the `PdfPCell` class (`new PdfPCell()`) in your code. For the Rectangle class, you are not actually using an *instance* of the class, but just accessing one of the constants it defines. To use a constant defined in a class, you don't need to instantiate it.

Comment: @yorah, if you want to elaborate more for the OP, the `new XYZ() {A = B}` syntax is C#'s object initializer syntax for setting properties at the same time as construction rather than one at a time later. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The using statement ensures that the instance being used will always be disposed of. There are other benefits associated with the using statement. Often times you will see the using statement in conjunction with system resources such as file handles and memory allocation. This ensures the handles are released when the function loses scope. See this reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for more info.

This is a wrapper class to encapsulate the functionality in the itextsharp.dll library. The developer of this code reused an existing class to encapsulate storing/retrieving data to configure the pdf cell attributes. This could have been done for many reasons, for example the cell configuration could be stored and read from an external configuration repository that uses the same class to get and set the cell attrinutes for this document, maybe a bit overkill however.

I bet the class was created to make the wrapper functionality more extensible. I could envision a class `public class PdfMargin` to encapsulate the configuration for the margins of the document. There you could define your margins in the constructor once and simply reference the margin class elsewhere in the code.